# Google Cloud functions not updating sourceArchiveUrl bug when redeployment

Tags: function, deployment, gcloud

Creating a google cloud function with gcloud like so:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy myfunction --region=us-central1 --entry-point=handler --source=gs://mybucket/code1.zip --stage-bucket=gs://mybucket --trigger-http
```

works the first time as the function is created from the code1.zip, however, when the same command is ran again after changing to a new zip like so:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy myfunction --region=us-central1 --entry-point=handler --source=gs://mybucket/code2.zip --stage-bucket=gs://mybucket --trigger-http
```

the function keeps on pointing to the old code1.zip file i.e. (sourceArchiveUrl: gs://mybucket/code1.zip). Is this an updated bug?

Comment: Can you run the second command with --log-http? I tried reproducing the issue but gcloud updated source code location. Also is your gcloud up to date (I tried with 172.0.1 and 173.0.0)?

Comment: I eventually figured out the bug, my script was accidentally passing the previous zip file name instead of the new one.

Comment: @Alappin so how did you fix that?

Comment: @stkvtflw I was accidentally passing in the same old zip name, so I changed my script to pass in the right zip name in the command. i.e code2.zip instead of code1.zip the second time around.